# Adding image to android listview 

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I'm trying to reference an image inside my java class. Since Im using simple_list_item_1, Im unsure how to pull this image in from my drawable folder. Any guidance would be much appreciated. Here is my code:

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity {

  private static String imageView45;

  String classes[] = { "menu item 1", "menu item 2" };

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView45);
    imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.listlogobgk);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
  }

  public static String getImageView45() {
    return imageView45;
  }

  public static void setImageView45(String imageView45) {
    Menu.imageView45 = imageView45;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String thisthing = classes[position];

    try {
      @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
      Class ourClass = Class.forName("my.package.android." + thisthing);
      Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
      startActivity(ourIntent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clear your question more. What you want inside your list view? Something regarding that?

Comment: My goal is to add an image to the listview, then display my list below that.

Comment: Okay, so for this. You need to extend your ArrayAdapter with your custom adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem can be solved by extending your own adapter from `ArrayAdapter`. After that, override your `getView()` method and `inflate` layout for this. Please follow this link [Check out 5.0 Example for extended adaper](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Hope, this will work easily!

Comment: Pleasure. If it worked then please mark question(Tick) for future ones. Thanks